# youtube loading icon over play button

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

When loading a youtube player with the api on an ios device which blocks autoplay, the loading icon keeps showing until "PLAY" is pressed, the problem is the loading icon is placed higher on zindex and blocks touch events of the play button, so you need to press around it, which leaves a very narrow gap for touch input.

Answer (score 0):

Using cueVideoById and trigger play if not on ios solves this problem, but I still think the loading icon should be transparent to touch inputs.